# Split name with spaces and store in different variables

Tags: string, split, lua

I have this name Zaid Bin Altaf. I want to split it with space not with length. I have split it but I have to store these 3 names in different variables
first name - Zaid
Middle name - Bin 
Surname - Altaf

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your name will have exactly three components, you can use `string.match`:

```lua
local name = "Zaid Bin Altaf"
local first_name, middle_name, last_name = name:match"^(%S+)%s(%S+)%s(%S+)$"
```

Explanation:

- `^`: Start of string
- `(%S+)`: One or more non-space characters, captured
- `%s`: Exactly one space character, not captured
- `$`: End of string

This pattern is rather strict; it accepts no leading or trailing whitespace and expects exactly three names, separated by exactly two spaces (in total).
You might want a more lax pattern such as `^%s*(%S+)%s+(%S+)%s+(%S+)%s*$`.

Alternatively, if you just want to "split by spaces", you can simply match sequences of one or more non-space characters using `gmatch` and insert the result into a table. This might look as follows:

```lua
local name = "Zaid Bin Altaf"
local names = {}
for part in name:gmatch"%S+" do
    table.insert(names, part)
end
```

Now you need to figure out what to do with the `names` table:

- Do you check the length? `assert(#names == 3, "first, middle & last name expected")` would work here.
- Do you unpack it to local variables (after having checked the length)? You could use `local first, middle, last = unpack(names)` for this.

Answer (score 0):

And of course with `gsub()` that use a function on the match to make exactly what you want.

```
local name = "Zaid Bin Altaf"

name:gsub('^(%w+)%s(%w+)%s(%w+)$', function(fn, mn ,sn) FirstName, MiddleName, Surname = fn, mn, sn return end)

print(FirstName, MiddleName, Surname)
```

Comment: I was tring this before 
a = "Zaid Bin Altaf"
for i in string.gmatch(fg, "%S+") do
ShowInfo(" i :" .. i)